# Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\www.itv.se\boreale\samieng.htm'

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, url, html-agility-pack

I have some URLs that are the result links of google search engine for a query which I want to get their title and descriptions. 
I send these URLs to

```
HtmlWeb w = new HtmlWeb();
string SearchResults = "http://google.com/search?q=" + query.querytxt;
var hd = w.Load(SearchResults);
var cites = hd.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//cite");
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

foreach (var cite in cites)
{
    url = cite.InnerText.Trim();

    WebClient x = new WebClient();

    string pageSource = x.DownloadString(url);

    var regex = @"\<title\b[^>]*\>\s*(?<Title>[\s\S]*?)\</title\>";

    query.title = Regex.Match(pageSource, regex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
                       .Groups["Title"].Value;
}
```

When I use this code for returning some titles of urls
for the third URL I get this error:

> Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\www.itv.se\boreale\samieng.htm'.

Best regards

Comment: Where exactly is the exception thrown? Set a breakpoint and see what part of the program causes it, obviously a bad url is being loaded, it should be just "www.itv.se\boreale\samieng.htm'".

Comment: @YoussefLourayad in this line string pageSource = x.DownloadString(url); i have the correct url  as u said is "www.itv.se\boreale\samieng.htm" . even it wors for first and seccond url at the third one it failes

Comment: Try prefixing it with "http://", `x.DownloadString("http://" + url)`.

Comment: @YoussefLourayad I get the error now "The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel." in this line "pageSource =(x.DownloadString("https://" + url));" and sometimes the error of  "Unable to connect to the remote server" for thoes sites which are filtered in iran like Youtube . do you know any other way to get title and description of google result links ?

Comment: Don't use regex to extract titles, and rather than a using a `WebClient` to load google results, load them into `HtmlWeb` same way you load the `SearchResults`, then select the Title node from the document.